# Is Acronis True Image always a true image?

Tags: backup, disk-image, acronis-trueimage

I am planing a full backup in my computer using Acronis for the first time. I know that there are two kinds of backup softwares, one that can only copy the files and restore them, but cannot restore a complete windows installation, thus the user will have to reinstall everything, and the other kind that makes a image of the system, being able to restore all its files and the system itself as a whole. 
The question is: Does Acronis True Image always make a full system image (when I select full backup) or there is some hidden option I have to select?
I know the software name says much, but I just want to confirm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Acronis True Image does both of the backups you described.

- **File Backups:** Only files and folders are compressed and stored
- **Disk/Partition Images:** Stores a sector-by-sector snapshot of the disk or partition.  This will include the operating system, drivers, registry, application, files, and any of your configuration

To do a complete backup (Disk/Partition), make sure you select **Disk and partition backup** on the **Backup and recovery** tab

See the Acronis user manual at http://www.acronis.com/support/documentation/ (under Acronis True Image Home) for more information

Comment: I have a SSD with my windows and a HDD with my files...if I do a partition backup, how the sector by sector will behave?

Comment: Do a disk/partition backup of your SSD, since all your system files are there. If your HDD only contains your personal data (images, documents, music, etc.), do a file backup for the HDD.

Comment: I did a disk backup for both o them, just did 2 different backups, one for the SSD and one for the HDD, so I believe this way each backup will have its own aligment

Comment: I will accept it, usually I just wait some days in case someone else shows up with a different perspective.